# Java cxf client can't recover when web service goes down and back up again

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

As the title says, we have a java cxf client for a web service which is out of our control. 
The problem is that if that web service goes down, when it comes back up again attempting to consume information from it eventually results in SocketTimeoutException from cxf.

If we restart our whole application consuming the web service works as expected.

Here is how we configure the http conduit in spring:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client AllowChunking="false" Connection="close" ReceiveTimeout="${webservices.timeout:30000}" ConnectionTimeout="${webservices.timeout:30000}" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Can anyone think of a reason our client can't recover?

Comment: I know this is a late comment but I'm experiencing the same issue, did you find a solution for this?